# How can <!--[if IE]> work AND NOT work?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, if-statement

According to the developer tools in IE9 this CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="one.css"> /*meyers reset*/
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="two.css"> /*the main one*/
<!--[if IE]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="IE.css"> 
<![endif]-->
```

is successful in that it results in the `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="IE.css">` being recognised/included.  However neither the stylesheet nor any of its declarations show in the tools/style panel.  None of its declarations function.

How can this be?

I've tested the stylesheet is not functioning by changing e.g the `color` declaration.

IE developer tools show only the main stylesheet `two.css` and the meyers reset `one.css` working

`one.css` isn't actually listed but there's no word wrap for the CSS panel (only for the main/html panel) and the horizontal scroll bar doesn't reach the end of its declarations (!) so there's no room to actually display the filename.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is being phased out and is now only supported by older versions of IE. I recently found this css snippet and everything within the media query occurs only in the IE browser.

EDIT: I am not sure if you should worry about IE9 since not even microsoft supports it anymore. The version is up to 11 now!

```
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
  /* Anything in here only occurs in IE */
}
```

Comment: I have another @media rule-set at the end of `two.css`and added your code in after that inserting `h1 {color: red;}` directly after its comment.  But although it does not change the `<h1>` to red in FF it also doesn't in IE9 so no joy.  Have I misunderstood something?

Comment: You may need to use `{color: red !important;}` to have it overwrite your original code but I am unsure without knowing more about your project.

Comment: :( nope that didn't do anything either.  Checked out the ms-high-contrast and the value `active` "Indicates that the subsequent styling rules will be applied when the system is placed in high contrast mode with any color variation." (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh771830%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: @talvi: IE9 doesn't support -ms-high-contrast. This rule only targets IE10 and IE11. This answer is telling you to simply ignore IE9. Which, of course, is not what you're looking for.

Comment: @BoltClock: RofLoL thanks!!  That's shut one rabbit hole.  I would ideally like to address all IE browsers but life's too short?

Answer (score 0):

> Conditional comments are gone in IE 9

This will work, only in IE browser

```
  <!--[if IE 9]><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href=“ie.css" /><![endif]-->
```

This will not work in IE it will be hidden, So you can add your main css files.

```
<!--[if !IE]--><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href=“one.css" /><!--[endif]-->

<!--[if !IE]--><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="two.css" /><!--[endif]-->
```

** Here's Paul Irish way of targeting IE Browsers **

```
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html class="ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html> <!--<![endif]-->
```

> Using HTML5 Shiv on an HTML5 web page is simple; you may do so with or without installation of the library. Below is an example of how to conditionally include HTML5 Shiv only for Internet Explorer browsers less-than version 9. The script should be included within the  element of the page, after any stylesheets:

```
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
```

> Conditional comments are gone in IE 10

Add the User Agent to the  element with a tiny bit of JavaScript

**JS:**

```
var b = document.documentElement;
b.setAttribute('data-useragent',  navigator.userAgent);
b.setAttribute('data-platform', navigator.platform );
```

**IE 10's User Agent string is:**

Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Trident/6.0)

Which will result in:

```
<html data-useragent="Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Trident/6.0)">
```

***And you can then style like:***

**CSS:**

```
html[data-useragent*='MSIE 10.0'] h1 {
  color: blue;
}
```

Check this on [Codepen.io](https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/Kcmzf)

[Main Source](https://css-tricks.com/ie-10-specific-styles/)

Comment: I am confused.  Help me out.  Why have you repeated the code I put in my original post (and from which what I detail has come) simply stating that it works?   The reason I posted here is that the code is NOT, for me, working - despite IE9's developer tools showing it as having been read (not commented out).  I know that it SHOULD work, but it DON'T.

Comment: And why (@Liam12 - I can't put that @ at the beginning) is your reply headed with a banner "Conditional comments are gone in IE 9" while your reply quotes the code which makes them work in IE9? (though not in my case somehow)

Comment: @talvi I didn't repeat your main code, you have to add [if IE 9] at the first, if that doesn't work you can try another way using HTML5 this only IE9 will read it <!--[if lt IE 9]>

Comment: Thanks Liamm12, I misread you.  
You say I have to specify each version of IE rather than just global IE, right and say it will be ignored otherwise ... and thar's the problem:  Looking at the page through IE9's developer tools the line of conditional-code IS being read by my IE9, but despite that it is not being executed.  
ps. I am using HTML5.